# changing the size of open3d point cloud

Tags: python, open3d

I am trying to visualize the point clouds using the following code but I can't find the way to adjacent the point size. Although there is a parameter `point_size=` with `o3d.visualization.draw([pcd], point_size=5)` but i want to use draw_geometries for this work. Any help will be much appreciated

```
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("000010.pcd")
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])
```

[image]

Comment: Can you specify a bit more what aspect of `draw_geometries` geometry you need? And what makes `o3d.visualization.draw` not a good fit in your use-case?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `+` to increase the point size and `-` to decrease the point size in the draw_geometry visualization window.

By the way, you can use `H` to get help information.

Comment: Which system is this on? It does not work on ARM macos, and a colleague reported amd64 linux also not working.

Comment: So it turns out the keys apply to qwerty layout … if you use qwertz or something you need to find the keys for your layout.

Comment: @oarfish Hi. Yes, I am using a qwerty layout keyboard. The system I use is Ubuntu 20.04 on Intel CPU.